# How to diagnostic establish connection slow

Tags: performance, iis

Recently I meet a weird problem, sometimes the browser will need about 20seconds  to establish connecting to the IIS web server

```
1. this cannot be repro each time, when successful access the site, the following connecting will be very fast. After restart Application pool and Web Site, the first time connect will be slow.<br>
2. When success gernerate connection success, after minutes, the establsh connection will getting slow again.<br>
3. this is not relate to authentication, both Windows Authentication and Anonmymous will have the same problem.<br>
4. Installed HTTPWatch on my client machine, it shows that 20 seconds is connecting time before wating when this problem happen.<br>
5. localhost cannot repro, each time establish connection is fast
```

From the log of IIS, then first request is get after

how to debug this? seems this is relate to the network, porxy, domain, is there some tool can help to diagnostic this problem, and can tell me what the server is doing during the time slot of establishing connection

Comment: You need to consult the vendor of the browser on how to collect the information you want. For Internet Explorer/Windows, you may open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com